# Rollupjs custom plugin adding dynamically new input entry during build cycle

Tags: plugins, rollupjs

is there a way to dynamically add new input entries during plugin build cycle?

Here: https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development/#resolveid
It is said:

> When resolving entry points, importer will usually be undefined. An exception here are entry points generated via `this.emitFile` as here, you can provide an importer argument.

So it is said that it is possible to generate entry points with `this.emitFile`. But at the same time, if we take a look at: https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development/#this-emitfile

> emittedFile: EmittedChunk | EmittedPrebuiltChunk | EmittedAsset

Emitted file can be only one of this 3 types which is not an input entry file.